# Test case failing regarding a mistake

Tags: html, css

This is a Lab I am doing with Udacity(Trading Cards). I am facing an error while submitting the project.

the instruction : 2. give the interesting facts `<div>` a CSS class of `animal-info`

this is my HTML code

```css
#container{
  border: 7.5px solid black;
   padding: 20px;
}
#card{
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#interesting-fact{
  font-style: italic;
}

.animal-info{
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 90%;
}

.animal_info{
  font-style: italic;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul {
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style: none;
}

h1{
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

img{
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

#summary{
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Building the Prototype</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Kitten</h1>
    <!-- photo credit: wikipedia.org, image taken by Ritik -->
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="Kitten">
    <div id="card">
      <div class="animal-info"> 
      <p id="interesting-fact"> 
         All kittens are born with blue eyes and will have their fully developed eye color at around 8 weeks old.
      </p></div>
      <ul id="facts">
        <li>
          <span>Scientific Name</span>: Caracal
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Average Length</span>: 14 to 16 inches
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Average Lifespan</span>: 15.1 years
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Habitat</span>: Houses.
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p id="summary">Cats were probably first kept because they ate mice, and this is still their main 'job' in farms throughout the world. Later they were kept because they are friendly and good companions. Their average lifespam is 15.1 years.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

this is my CSS code
```

the error is : The trading card page with styling has an info section below the image with class 'animal-info'
The #card element does not have class 'animal-info': expected false to equal true

Comment: Perhaps they were looking for `<div id="card" class="animal-info">`?

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container{
  border: 7.5px solid black;
   padding: 20px;
}
#card{
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#interesting-fact{
  font-style: italic;
  
}

#interesting-fact{
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 90%;
}

#card.animal_info{
  font-style: italic;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul {
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style: none;
}

h1{
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

img{
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

#summary{
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Building the Prototype</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Kitten</h1>
    <!-- photo credit: wikipedia.org, image taken by Ritik -->
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="Kitten">
    <div id="card" class="animal-info" >
       
      <p id="interesting-fact" > 
         All kittens are born with blue eyes and will have their fully developed eye color at around 8 weeks old.
        </p></div>
      <ul id="facts">
        <li>
          <span>Scientific Name</span>: Caracal
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Average Length</span>: 14 to 16 inches
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Average Lifespan</span>: 15.1 years
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Habitat</span>: Houses.
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p id="summary">Cats were probably first kept because they ate mice, and this is still their main 'job' in farms throughout the world. Later they were kept because they are friendly and good companions. Their average lifespam is 15.1 years.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please visit help center, take tour to see what and How to Ask. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a Stacksnippet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change the .animal_info in css to #animal_info?

Give that a shot!

Have you tried this?
Give that a try and if it doesn't work let me know?

Answer (score 0):

It says to give the interesting facts  a CSS class of animal-info. You need to add the class to the div mentioned. You have the animal-info wrapping the interesting-facts div. See bellow

```css
#container{
  border: 7.5px solid black;
   padding: 20px;
}
#card{
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#interesting-fact{
  font-style: italic;
}

#interesting-fact.animal-info{
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 90%;
}

.animal_info{
  font-style: italic;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul {
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style: none;
}

h1{
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

img{
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

#summary{
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Building the Prototype</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Kitten</h1>
    <!-- photo credit: wikipedia.org, image taken by Ritik -->
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="Kitten">
    <div id="card">
      <div class="animal-info"> 
      <p id="interesting-fact" class="animal-info"> 
         All kittens are born with blue eyes and will have their fully developed eye color at around 8 weeks old.
      </p></div>
      <ul id="facts">
        <li>
          <span>Scientific Name</span>: Caracal
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Average Length</span>: 14 to 16 inches
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Average Lifespan</span>: 15.1 years
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Habitat</span>: Houses.
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p id="summary">Cats were probably first kept because they ate mice, and this is still their main 'job' in farms throughout the world. Later they were kept because they are friendly and good companions. Their average lifespam is 15.1 years.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

this is my CSS code
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they were looking for `<div id="card" class="animal-info">`?

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="card" class="animal-info">`

I'm going through the same problem, and this worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just already faced same obstacle in Udacity Lab
here is the key :)
Thanks for sharing your challenge here!

```
<div id="card" class="animal-info" >
```

in your code, you made another nested div instead of giving a class to the same **div** that has the `id="card"`

this will help you later to make a border and padding for the whole div.
in your `CSS` style file, you need to make `.animal-info {}` and style it.

also, there will be a requirement to make padding for the #card as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Of course,I had the same mistake:

> The trading card page with styling has a 'list of facts' labels that
> are bold expected '400' to be one of [ '700', 'bold' ]
> ---------for: 
> ------- Answer:
> #interestign-fact:font-style:bold;//or 400,700;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31498289)